# Directory structure of tomcat project in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I see a few different formats of directories in eclipse for tomcat in different examples. 
Is there a "preferred" structure one should follow. The default that Eclipse created for Tomcat project was as follows:

```
/projectName
../src
../bin
../WEB-INF
../../lib
../../src
../../classes
```

- Where would javascript,css files be place?
- What is top level src normally for?
- Why change or set web application root? I know these directories could be moved around. Just need to set different configure params.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where would javascript,css files be place? **src/main/webapp/css  src/main/webapp/js**

What is top level src normally for? **yes, src/main/java src/main/resources src/test/java src/test/resources**

I suggest you use a Maven project type. In Eclipse: New > Project... > Maven > Maven Project

Comment: thanks. Have dated eclipse/tomcat projects. Do not wont to repeat. Forgot about Maven.